# Save Azure Functions invocation Traces in files

Tags: logging, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I would Like to save the content of all of my invocation Traces of specific Azure Functions in différent files with an automatic purge.
For exemple keep all the calls on the last 3 days.
I need the invocation details on each file generated :
[image]

Currently I only have acces to the last 20 operations :
[image]

Is it something possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I only have acces to the last 20 operations.

If you see from the Azure Portal Function App > Function > Monitor, only 20 invocations will be visible:

[image]

From the Same page, click on "**Run query in Application Insights**" > Remove the code `take 20` from the query:
[image]

and then run the query in the logs where you'll get all the invocation traces:
[image]

Note: `take n` here n is the number of traces/rows.

> I would Like to save the content of all of my invocation Traces of specific Azure Functions in different files with an automatic purge. For example, keep all the calls on the last 3 days. I need the invocation details on each file generated:

[image]

You can save the invocation traces for every execution in CSV or Excel or export to PowerBI Reports also where you can keep the time range in query from which duration, the logs are required.

**Note**: *All the Functions Invocation traces can be saved automatically in the associated storage account file shares*.

These invocation logs are stored in Storage Account File Shares that are sent to Log Analytics Workspace linked with the Application Insights created during Azure Function App. You can purge the logs using Portal, PowerShell and REST API. Refer to Azure Monitor logs delete workspace [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/delete-workspace).

Comment: Great and well detailled answer

Finnaly, i used the query module to get the exact logs i need